# How to prevent HTTP 404 during deployment of ear in Wildfly/Jboss

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

We're using WildFly 10 as our application server and deploy via Docker (deployment in WF is ordinary hotdeployment). We're not using WildFly's clustering mechanisms but simply have load-balancers (HAProxys) in front.

The problem is that WF opens its HTTP port while the EAR deployment is still in progress. This (of course?) leads to HTTP 404 errors which we don't want to handle specifically in the LBs. This could lead to false negatives...

**Is there a way to allow HTTP connections only after the EAR has started successfully?**

Alternatively is it possible to replace the "404 because nothing is deployed here"-error with a "503 service unavailable"? This would much better express the problem and would be easy to handle externally...

Comment: We have similar setup and also tried to deal with this situation. haproxy is configured to make health checks on our simple service in EAR that returns Http 200 only when deployment is completed (check is done via jmx.. ). I'm looking for simpler solution too.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want introduce **another** health check. ctomc's solution sounds good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set default-response-code for host you are running this on.

something along the lines:

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost" default-response-code="503">
```

or in cli:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host:write-attribute(name=default-response-code, value=503)
```

and similarly for any other host you might have.

Comment: Very nice. Do I have to list each host or can I do e.g. "*"?

Comment: Worked very well! I simply left "localhost" and it did work fine. One question though: How did you know about this config? Where is a good place to look? I find the Wildfly docs severely lacking...

Comment: Well, I was involved in adding the feature :) for model docs I would recommend using Wildscribe https://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/10.0.0.Final/subsystem/undertow/server/host/index.html which shows all model details/configuration options

Comment: If you configure it via XML (which I would discourage) you can always look at xsd schema you can find in docs/schema of the distribution. For undertow subsystem itself you can also find them in sources at: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/tree/10.0.0.Final/undertow/src/main/resources/schema

Comment: Does anyone know how to customise the 503 page content for the human user ? HTTP 503 is good for load balancers but **503 - Service Unavailable** is not ideal for human viewers.

Comment: EDIT - found a solution. If you follow guidance here [link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/251980) but substitute 404 for 503 it works.

Comment: This Answer alone did not work for me on wildfly 16. I had to remove the enclosed location tag to make it work. https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/undertow-dev/2017-January/001861.html